# Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 341211 -- Error in json.load

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to load a json file using python in pycharm, but seems that the `json.load()` doesn't quite get my json format.

My json is like this:

```
{"User_id":"304062","First_name":"client1_first_name ","Last_name":"client1_last_name","Email":"client1emailemailemail@gmail.com","City":"vitoria","Country":"country_code","Reservas":"0","Unsubscribe":"0"}
{"User_id":"1372","First_name"client2firstname".","Last_name":"client2lastname","Email":"tralala@blabla.com","City":"nop","Country":"bra","Reservas":"0","Unsubscribe":"0"}
```

The code I am using is as it follows:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
    with open('path_to_my_json/my_json.json',) as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
        print(data)
    pprint(data[0])
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 341211 column 1 (char 163 - 58075195)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your exact json output?  It's invalid

Comment: Is that line 341211 ? Should it be -- > `{"User_id":"1372","First_name":"client2firstname","Last_name":"client2lastname","Email":"tralala@blabla.com","City":"nop","Country":"bra","Reservas":"0","Unsubscribe":"0"}` ?

Comment: better to dump the whole blob of JSON in a validator instead of picking at one line

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with JSON files. I exported a table from bigquery to the gcloud console and chosed the JSON format, than I downloaded it. So gcloud kind of did everything for me. Now, I am just trying to load this JSON. I had already gone through the JSON validator. But since I am new to this, I didn't quite get what were happening or what is missing. The validator I went through gives me the following error: "Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'". I just thought that it was kind of weird for gcloud to give me an invalid json file. Is that normal to happen in other platforms?

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid JSON:

```
{"User_id":"1372","First_name"client2firstname".","Last_name":"client2lastname","Email":"tralala@blabla.com","City":"nop","Country":"bra","Reservas":"0","Unsubscribe":"0"}
```

Validate your JSON before loading it:
https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since being asked, but I just ran across the same problem and solved it like this:

```
tweets = []
for line in open('tweets.json', 'r'):
    tweets.append(json.loads(line))
```

I found this solution here: https://izziswift.com/python-json-loads-shows-valueerror-extra-data/  (it's solution 2).